# Problema al querer Actualizar JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Estoy utilizando Java con JPA y tengo una entidad festival y otra festivalEdicion. Un festival puede tener muchas ediciones. La cuestion que cuando doy de alta una edicion, luego de hacer em.persist, tengo que hacer

```
   res.getFestival().getFestivalEdicions().add(res);

   em.merge(res.getFestival());
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer que jpa se entere de los cambios y se actualice?

El metodo completo del create es:

```
 @Override
@MethodName(name = MethodsNameAgam.FESTIVALEDICION_ADD)
public FestivalEdicion create(FestivalEdicionTran tran) throws Exception {
    assign(tran, Op.CREATE);
    validate(tran, Op.CREATE);
    FestivalEdicion res = tran.build(Op.CREATE);

    if (tran.getPortada() != null && tran.getPortada().isSet()) {
        Contenido portada = contenidoCont.create(tran.getPortada());
        res.setPortada(portada);
    }

    em.persist(res);

    //AGREGAR A LA LSITA DE EDCIONES DEL FESTIVAL, LA EDICIONE CREADA
    res.getFestival().getFestivalEdicions().add(res);

    em.merge(res.getFestival());

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Puedes ampliar tu pregunta no entiendo que quieres hacer o cual es tu problema

Comment: Extremo cuidado con cascade = ALL. En caso de inicializar las relaciones con Lazy, deberias recuperarlas antes de actualizar la entidad Festival, puesto que si no realizara un delete de las entidades Edicion relacionadas

Answer (score 1):

Si, con cascadas. 
Me imagino que la asociacion entre Festival y Edicion es algo asi:

```
@Entity
class Festival {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "festival", cascade = ALL)
  List<Edicion> ediciones;
}
```

El atributo cascade=ALL hace que todas las operaciones aplicadas a Festival se propaguen a Edicion. Si ademas quieres que al quitar una edicion de la lista se elimine de la base de datos, puedes hacer:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "festival", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Tambien es posible no propagar todas las operaciones sino solo algunas. Para mas informacion lee este articulo: [Hibernate JPA cascade types](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/).

Por cierto, si la adicion de Edicion a Festival ocurre en la misma transaccion en la que guardaste (persist) el festival, no es necesario incorporar (merge) los cambios de nuevo, porque el EntityManager ya esta monitoreando cambios adicionales a partir de que lo guardas.