# Problema con JPA, no se actualiza la @Entity referenciada

Tags: jsf, jpa

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación jsf2.3 con PostgreSQL utilizando JPA como ORM y server Glassfish 4.1. Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una @Entity Creador y una Contrato, donde el Contrato conoce (llave foránea) quien es su creador.

Resumiendo:

Creador tiene lista de Contratos.

Contrato referencia a un Creador.

El Problema:

Si se da de alta a un Creador se actualzan sus contratos. Pero

Si se de de alta un Contrato por separado (siempre asignandole el Crador), al pedir lista de contratos del creador no aparece el Contrato recién creado.

A continuación les dejo el código que interviene en el problema para una mejor comprensión.

---

```java
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author yoyo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "contrato")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByContratoPk", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.contratoPk = :contratoPk")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByImporteCreadorCuc", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.importeCreadorCuc = :importeCreadorCuc")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByImporteCreadorCup", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.importeCreadorCup = :importeCreadorCup")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByNoCttoCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.noCttoCliente = :noCttoCliente")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByNoCttoCreador", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.noCttoCreador = :noCttoCreador")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Contrato.findByFechaContrato", query = "SELECT c FROM Contrato c WHERE c.fechaContrato = :fechaContrato")})
public class Contrato implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUST_SEQ2")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "contrato_contrato_pk_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ2")
    @Column(name = "contrato_pk")
    private Integer contratoPk;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "importe_creador_cuc")
    private double importeCreadorCuc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "importe_creador_cup")
    private double importeCreadorCup;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "no_ctto_cliente")
    private String noCttoCliente;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "no_ctto_creador")
    private String noCttoCreador;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fecha_contrato")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaContrato;
    @JoinColumn(name = "creador_fk", referencedColumnName = "creador_pk")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Creador creadorFk;
    @JoinColumn(name = "empresa_fk", referencedColumnName = "empresa_pk")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private EmpresaMediadora empresaFk;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ficha_costo_fk", referencedColumnName = "ficha_costo_pk")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private FichaCosto fichaCostoFk;

    public Contrato() {
    }

    public Contrato(Integer contratoPk) {
        this.contratoPk = contratoPk;
    }

    public Contrato(Integer contratoPk, double importeCreadorCuc, double importeCreadorCup, String noCttoCliente, String noCttoCreador, Date fechaContrato) {
        this.contratoPk = contratoPk;
        this.importeCreadorCuc = importeCreadorCuc;
        this.importeCreadorCup = importeCreadorCup;
        this.noCttoCliente = noCttoCliente;
        this.noCttoCreador = noCttoCreador;
        this.fechaContrato = fechaContrato;
    }

    public Integer getContratoPk() {
        return contratoPk;
    }

    public void setContratoPk(Integer contratoPk) {
        this.contratoPk = contratoPk;
    }

    public double getImporteCreadorCuc() {
        return importeCreadorCuc;
    }

    public void setImporteCreadorCuc(double importeCreadorCuc) {
        this.importeCreadorCuc = importeCreadorCuc;
    }

    public double getImporteCreadorCup() {
        return importeCreadorCup;
    }

    public void setImporteCreadorCup(double importeCreadorCup) {
        this.importeCreadorCup = importeCreadorCup;
    }

    public String getNoCttoCliente() {
        return noCttoCliente;
    }

    public void setNoCttoCliente(String noCttoCliente) {
        this.noCttoCliente = noCttoCliente;
    }

    public String getNoCttoCreador() {
        return noCttoCreador;
    }

    public void setNoCttoCreador(String noCttoCreador) {
        this.noCttoCreador = noCttoCreador;
    }

    public Date getFechaContrato() {
        return fechaContrato;
    }

    public void setFechaContrato(Date fechaContrato) {
        this.fechaContrato = fechaContrato;
    }

    public Creador getCreadorFk() {
        return creadorFk;
    }

    public void setCreadorFk(Creador creadorFk) {
        this.creadorFk = creadorFk;
    }

    public EmpresaMediadora getEmpresaFk() {
        return empresaFk;
    }

    public void setEmpresaFk(EmpresaMediadora empresaFk) {
        this.empresaFk = empresaFk;
    }

    public FichaCosto getFichaCostoFk() {
        return fichaCostoFk;
    }

    public void setFichaCostoFk(FichaCosto fichaCostoFk) {
        this.fichaCostoFk = fichaCostoFk;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (contratoPk != null ? contratoPk.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Contrato)) {
            return false;
        }
        Contrato other = (Contrato) object;
        if ((this.contratoPk == null && other.contratoPk != null) || (this.contratoPk != null && !this.contratoPk.equals(other.contratoPk))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Contrato[ contratoPk=" + contratoPk + " ]";
    }   
}


package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author yoyo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "creador")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByCreadorPk", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.creadorPk = :creadorPk")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByApellidos", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.apellidos = :apellidos")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByCi", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.ci = :ci")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByDir", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.dir = :dir")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByNoRegistroCreador", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.noRegistroCreador = :noRegistroCreador")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByNombre", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Creador.findByTel", query = "SELECT c FROM Creador c WHERE c.tel = :tel")})
public class Creador implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUST_SEQ3")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "creador_creador_pk_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ3")
    @Column(name = "creador_pk")
    private Integer creadorPk;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    private String apellidos;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "ci")
    private String ci;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "dir")
    private String dir;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "no_registro_creador")
    private String noRegistroCreador;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "tel")
    private String tel;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "creadorFk")
    private List<Contrato> contratoList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "creadorFk")
    private List<PagoFacturaCreador> pagoFacturaCreadorList;
    @Transient
    private Double pendienteXcobrarCup;
    @Transient
    private Double pendienteXcobrarCuc;

    public Creador() {
    }

    public Creador(Integer creadorPk) {
        this.creadorPk = creadorPk;
    }

    public Creador(Integer creadorPk, String apellidos, String ci, String noRegistroCreador, String nombre) {
        this.creadorPk = creadorPk;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.ci = ci;
        this.noRegistroCreador = noRegistroCreador;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Integer getCreadorPk() {
        return creadorPk;
    }

    public void setCreadorPk(Integer creadorPk) {
        this.creadorPk = creadorPk;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getCi() {
        return ci;
    }

    public void setCi(String ci) {
        this.ci = ci;
    }

    public String getDir() {
        return dir;
    }

    public void setDir(String dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public String getNoRegistroCreador() {
        return noRegistroCreador;
    }

    public void setNoRegistroCreador(String noRegistroCreador) {
        this.noRegistroCreador = noRegistroCreador;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public List<Contrato> getContratoList() {
        return contratoList;
    }

    public void setContratoList(List<Contrato> contratoList) {
        this.contratoList = contratoList;
    }

    public List<PagoFacturaCreador> getPagoFacturaCreadorList() {
        return pagoFacturaCreadorList;
    }

    public void setPagoFacturaCreadorList(List<PagoFacturaCreador> pagoFacturaCreadorList) {
        this.pagoFacturaCreadorList = pagoFacturaCreadorList;
    }

    public Double getPendienteXcobrarCup() {
        return pendienteXcobrarCup;
    }

    public void setPendienteXcobrarCup(Double pendienteXcobrarCup) {
        this.pendienteXcobrarCup = pendienteXcobrarCup;
    }
    public Double getPendienteXcobrarCuc() {
        return pendienteXcobrarCuc;
    }

    public void setPendienteXcobrarCuc(Double pendienteXcobrarCuc) {
        this.pendienteXcobrarCuc = pendienteXcobrarCuc;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (creadorPk != null ? creadorPk.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Creador)) {
            return false;
        }
        Creador other = (Creador) object;
        if ((this.creadorPk == null && other.creadorPk != null) || (this.creadorPk != null && !this.creadorPk.equals(other.creadorPk))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Creador[ creadorPk=" + creadorPk + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes explicarme un poco mas el error que no te entiendo mucho

Comment: Hola, el error es el sgte: supón que tienes un creador, llamémosle c1, y un contrato, llamemosle ctto, si yo digo ctto.getCreadoresList().add(c1), y luego ctto.merge(), esto se guarda en bd, y al decir ctto.getCreadoresList(), me retorna una lista con los creadores asociados a ctto q contiene a c1 (persistencia en cascada). Peros si por el contrario hacemos lo siguiente: c1.setContrato(ctto), y luego c1.merge(), c1 se guarda bien en BD, pero luego cuando digo ctto.getCredoresList(), esta lista no contiene a c1, cosa que no debería pasar puesto que c1 referencia a ctto y se guardo bien en BD.

Comment: Suele pasar con jpa lo que puedes hacer es una consulta credoresList, lo que traiga la lista puedes hacer un set, estas seguro que se guarda en la base de datos

Comment: Puedes explicarte mejor por favor, no entiendo lo que quieres decir, gracias. En cuanto a si se guarda bien en la BD la respuesta es SI, estoy seguro. De hecho si le pido al EntityManger todos los creadores, algo como creadoresFacade.findAll(), esta lista contiene a  c1, y c1 contiene a ctto, en su referencia al contrato. Pero si ejecuto lo mismo para el contrato contratoFacade.findAll(), y busco en esa lista a ctto, en su lista de creadores sigue sin incluirme a c1. Es como si no se actualizara su estado, lo cual no debería pasar dado que estoy utilizando @Stateless beans.

Comment: No he identificado cual es el error pero siento que puede ser la forma como realizaste las relaciones de la base de datos, en este caso puedes hacer createNamedQuery o puedes hacer una consulta a la tabla me imagino que con el id del creador

Comment: Eso ya lo he intentado, con una consulta sql funciona, pero entonces : para que un ORM ? por otro lado con los named query  o con criteriaQuery, sigue sin incluirme la entidad dependiente en la lista de dependencias de la superior cuando realizo la persistencia desde la dependiente. Buscando un poco encontre una pregunta antigua [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200373/problema-al-querer-actualizar-jpa?rq=1)  donde pasa lo mismo pero su solucion es precisamente lo que yo no quiero hacer que es utilizar la entidad superior.